# Authentication in couchdb for ios

Tags: iphone, authentication, couchdb

I am working on the couchdb . I am  using the  replication  between remote server and local server . I want to user the user name and password on the header field  in the encrypted format in the couch cocoa frame work . 
 i am getting this error Replicator: couldn't write document `_design/sample`, revision `1-53ef232135548f38c879df297b886c99`, to target database `iphone`. Error: `unauthorized`, reason: `You are not a db or server admin.`.

Replicator, request GET to "http:*******///iphone/_changes?feed=continuous&heartbeat=10000&style=all_docs&since=0" failed due to error timeout

i tried to add the set credential methods , but i need to use int he encrypted format  plz help me 
Thanks&regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already asked this question (three times) in the mobile-couchbase Google group. For completeness I'll just link to the thread there, with the reply I already posted this morning:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mobile-couchbase/AVpUCseNnIg